# I need help with divergence and gradient?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, differentiation

$$A_z = \mu{\frac{e^{-jBr}}{4\pi r}}∫I(z')e^{jBz'\cos\theta}dz'$$

Midway into my question, I want to compute:

$$-j\left( \frac{\nabla(\nabla\cdot A) }{w\mu\varepsilon} \right).$$

Symbols like $ w, \mu, \varepsilon, B $ are basically constants for things like frequency, permittivity, permeability and $r$ is just radius.

The result would be something like $ A_z \cos\theta \hat r$. I don't really know how to go about doing a divergence on this, and then a gradient. I did calc3 about 4 years ago, and between I have forgotten a lot. I need help at this step, if anyone needed the full problem, just comment.

Comment: If it helps at all, $\nabla^2 A=\nabla(\nabla\cdot A) - \nabla\times(\nabla\times A)$, where $\nabla^2 A$ is the vector laplacian.

Comment: In fact, this is a nice cheat sheet for vector calculus identities. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities

Comment: how do u go about it? could u get at least the dot, and i can get the gradient. am stuck

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: this is more like I wanna know how its done, this is just a middle step. the real question is way longer than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $A_z$ is only a function of $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $\theta$ (the integral over $z'$ is not a function of $z$, but does depend on $\theta$). I.e.,
$$
A_z=\frac{\mu e^{-iBr}}{4\pi r}{\tt C(\theta)}
$$

Since only (apparently) $A_z$ is non-zero we only need to be able to take the derivative w.r.t. $z$ to get $\nabla \cdot A_z$.
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec A = \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z}
$$
But since $A_z=A_z(r)$
$$
\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial r}\cos(\theta)-\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial \theta}\sin(\theta)
$$
since, e.g.,
$$
\frac{dr}{dz}=\frac{z}{r}=\cos(\theta)\;,
$$
and so on... Also, there's still another application of the gradient to get your final answer... give it a shot.